# ¿Cómo reemplazar el caracter decimal a mostrar de números que vienen en un JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

En un JSON tengo la siguiente información y quiero darle formato a los resultados, necesito mostrarlos asi:

> Dolar = 714,77  Euro = 789,10 UF = 28.013

Y me los entrega asi la api:

> Dolar = 724.37  Euro = 804.23  UF = 28065.35

```
$.getJSON('https://mindicador.cl/api', function (data) {
   var indicador = data;
   $("<p/>", {
      html:"<h1>Indicador Economico</h1>" + 'Valor UF = ' + indicador.uf.valor + "<p/>" + 'Valor Euro = ' + indicador.euro.valor + "<p/>" + 'Valor Dolar = ' + indicador.dolar.valor
   }).appendTo("body");
}).fail(function () {
   console.log('Error al consumir la API');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suponiendo que la data la trae de forma correcta, simplemente deberías hacer lo siguiente

```
$.getJSON('https://mindicador.cl/api', data => {
   const indicador = data;
   $("<p/>", {
      html:`<h1>Indicador Economico</h1> <p>Valor UF = ${Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {maximumSignificantDigits: 3}).format(indicador.uf.valor)}<p/> <p>Valor Euro = ${indicador.euro.valor}<p/> <p>Valor Dolar = ${(indicador.dolar.valor).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",")}<p/>`
   }).appendTo("body");
}).fail(() => console.log('Error al consumir la API'););
```

Corregí un poco la forma en que concatenas los elementos del DOM, ya que si estas utilizando *JavaScript (EcmaScript 6)*, puedes usar la característica de **Template String**; además faltaban aperturas y cierres de los tags `p`.

Para el dólar simplemente deberías usar un **[replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace)** para cambiar los puntos por comas, y un **[toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toFixed)** para indicar el número de decimales que quieres mostrar; y para la UF, la opción es usar **[Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NumberFormat)** donde le indicas el idioma, y un `maximumSignificantDigits` para desplegar los decimales.

Te dejo un ejemplo más practico para que veas su funcionalidad

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let number = [724.37, 28065.35]
  console.log(`Dolar: ${(number[0].toFixed(2).replace('.', ','))} | UF: ${Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {maximumSignificantDigits: 3}).format(number[1])}`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Aclarar que acá no estas convirtiendo un JSON a string, sino simplemente concatenando valores y mostrándolos

Nos comentas si te sirvió :)

Comment: Me los sigue mostrando con el mismo formato del json, no ha cambiado nada, pero la data la trae de manera correcta.

Comment: Momento! necesitas que te cambie los puntos por comas? Es eso?

Comment: Claro, aparte de darle formato a la uf, o redondearlo

Comment: @LukasBustos editada! Revisa y me comentas

Comment: sirvio. muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien estas buscando cambiar los puntos por las comas. Verdad? 
podrías usar ejemplo:

```
var importe = indicador.uf.valor; 

importe.toString().replace(/\./g,',');
```

esto reemplaza el punto por la coma

https://jsbin.com/huwekusoti/edit?js,console